# Display a message instead of a dropdown list when the array received is empty in knockout

Tags: asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

I am developping an asp.net mvc app and I have a cshtml view with a knockout directive :

```
<select data-bind="options: choices"></select>
```

When I received a filled array, everything is working well I got a dropdown list where I can select one element.
The problem is that when I received an empty array, the dropdown list is still displayed but without anything to choose, so it's kind
of ugly. I would like to know if it's possible in the knockout direct in my cshtml, to add a condition to said :
If my choices contains no element, display a label (with a message) instead of an empty dropdown list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the following is pretty self-explanatory:

```
<!-- ko if:choices().length > 0 -->
    <select data-bind="options: choices"></select>
<!-- /ko -->
<!-- ko if:choices().length == 0 -->
    I love tea
<!-- /ko -->
```

Comment: Beat me to it but I think you can even do `if:choices()`

Comment: @jumpingcode Yes, but I think for the sake of a clear example, it's better not to coerce and leave that as a decision for the OP to make.

Comment: You answer was almost perfect. I remove the "()" and now it's working. Thanks

Comment: @user2443476 I assumed that `choices` was an observable, but from what you say, this appears not to be the case.